# Delete Key is not triggering KeyUp & KeyDown Event

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am currently dealing with a multi-form application and am having issue registering a del key press, the application that requires the del key is a form with a frame on it with objects painted on it that can be selected, upon pressing the del key the selected objects are to be deleted via a deleteObjects method. The code I am currently using is as follows

```
void __fastcall TF_Image::KeyUpKbd( WORD &Key )
{
     if(Key == VK_DELETE || Key == VK_DKEY)
     {
          deleteSelectedObjects();
     }
}
```

(Note: There are other paramenters in the function call but they aren't used)

TF_Image inherits from TFrame

I have tried mapping other keys other than the del key ie the D key and have found that the method is called with no problem. I have discovered that when pressing (physically) the del key the methods associated with KeyUp & KeyDown are not called.

Edit: So i've attempted to add the DeleteSelectedOb() method to my WndProc method without much luck either.

```
void __fastcall TF_ImgBrowserOA::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (Message.WParam == VK_DELETE)
        {
            F_Image->DeleteSelectedOb();
        }
    } 
    //code that manages window resize
    TForm::WndProc(Message);
}
```

The WndProc method doent appear to respond to keystrokes

Comment: Your question title was "Delete Key is not triggering KeyPress Event", as you've noticed and now edited. That's what I based my answer on, but if that's not the event you're using, then yes, my answer won't help you. The Delete key should cause key down and up events to be raised, assuming the control is the one with the keyboard focus, unless some other component is handling them before your own event handlers get that chance. Does it work if you try it on a clean form with no other components?

Comment: There are no other KeyUp or KeyDown event handlers on any other forms in my application, the first thing i attempt to check was its response on the first form loaded on execution and once again the events didn't trigger, i suspect it's a system thing that handles the events before my form is aloud to, so whether there is a way to override the behaviour

Comment: I have a similar problem when working with a TMemo in XE3, except that OnKeyUp is the only event the delete key will trigger.

Comment: Have you tried to respond directly to the WM_KEYDOWN message in the WindowProc function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after cleaning up some code in some other modules and removing unneccessary menu's I decided to go back and look at this section again after I found a similar piece of code implementing a similar function, I couldn't see much difference between them and so I recompiled and attempted to run my Delete function from the KeyDown event and for some reason it just worked, I suspect it came down to an issue of another element holding focus in the Application. As a precaution I also called a SetFocus() to the frame in which I required this code to operate in. Its still a mystery to me why this didn't work intially though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet for my TRichEdit control (Script_Edit).

```
TWndMethod *PrevWndProc = Script_Edit->WindowProc;
Script_Edit->WindowProc = MyWndProc;

void __fastcall My_Form::MyWndProc(TMessage &Message) {

  switch (Message.Msg) {

    case WM_KEYDOWN: {
      // Check for DELETE and BACKSPACE keys
      if( Message.WParam == VK_BACK  ||
          Message.WParam == VK_DELETE
        ) {
             // Do whatever you need
          }
      break;

    default:
      // call default handler if not processed
      PrevWndProc(Message);

  }
}
```

You can't get much closer to the message core than this with VCL...

Comment: So I've attempt something along the lines of what you suggested, my WndProc method also handles the mouse drag associated with resizing a window